# Object oriented design for running multiple algorithms

Tags: c#, object-oriented-analysis

I have a base class `Node` doing heavy works of a simulator. And I have some different algorithms using the same base class, So I have inherited `NodeA` and `NodeB` from `Node`. And there is another class which does the hardwork for visual representation. These nodes are able to run and work without the visual representation, therefore they are in different library projects.

What I couldn't do is, if you like at class `VisualNode` I can only inherit from one of the classes at a time when I'm running my visual application, and I actually initialize instances of `VisualNode` to start the job. I want to provide the user to be able to select which algorithm to run.

What is the correct design in this case? And please keep the virtual hooker methods in mind too.

Below are my classes:

```
public abstract class Node
{
    protected abstract void UserDefined_ReceiveMessageProcedure ( Message m );

    public virtual void VisualizeMessage ( Message m )
    {
        /// hooker method for visual interfaces - empty block in this class will be overriden in derived class
    }
}

public class NodeA : Node
{
    protected override void UserDefined_ReceiveMessageProcedure ( Message receivedMessage )
    {
        /// real implementation lies here
        ....
        /// VisualizeMessage is called in here
    }
}

public class NodeB : Node
{
    protected override void UserDefined_ReceiveMessageProcedure ( Message receivedMessage )
    {
        /// real implementation lies here
        ....
        /// VisualizeMessage is called in here
    }
}
```

And there is another class which is supposed to be able to behave like both of these:

```
public class VisualNode : NodeA // NodeB 
{
    public Brush NodeColor { get; set; }
    ....

    public VisualNode ( ... )
    {
        /// some setup
    }

    public bool OnIt ( Point p )
    {
        /// some checks
    }
    public void Draw ( ... )
    {
        /// draw it
    }

    public override void VisualizeMessage ( AsyncSimulator.Message m )
    {
        /// visualizing the message
        /// this method is called via superclass
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't put the empty VisualizeMessage in Node? If you're just going to have one in each derived class it seems like it could be in the base class.

Comment: Yes that'll be a better approach.

Comment: I admit this is a better approach. And I will be very happy to hear any suggestions for the actual problem too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than `VirtualNode` inherits from `NodeA` or `NodeB`, let it use NodeA or NodeB.

It is always better to Perfer Composistion over Inheritance. You've to choose the one which makes more sense. In this scenario, composition makes more sense as clearly inheritance can't solve your problem(at least easily).

You can implement it as a [Decorator pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator) or [Strategy pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy). With first approach `VirtualNode` will inherit from `Node` and wrap another `Node` too. Latter doesn't inherit from `Node` but uses Node.

Or even better, Just throw away VisualNode and inject a Visualizer(strategy pattern) to Node.

```
public abstract class Node
{
    public IMessageVisualizer MessageVisualizer { get; set; }
    protected abstract void UserDefined_ReceiveMessageProcedure(Message m);
    protected void VisualizeMessage(Message m)
    {
        MessageVisualizer.Visualize(m);
    }
}

public interface IMessageVisualizer
{
    void Visualize(Message m);
}

public class MessageVisualizer : IMessageVisualizer
{
    public Brush NodeColor { get; set; }

    public void Visualize(Message m)
    {
        /// visualizing the message
    }

    public bool OnIt()
    {
        /// some checks
    }
    public void Draw()
    {
        /// draw it
    }
}
```

Your NodeA and NodeB stays same. You can use it as

```
Node node = new NodeA();
node.MessageVisualizer = new MessageVisualizer();
node.DoSomethingThatMightVisualize();
```

And when you don't want to visualize, you can provide a empty implementation of MessageVisualizer like the following

```
public class NullVisualizer : IMessageVisualizer
{
    public void Visualize(Message m)
    {
        //Don't visualize
    }
}

Node node = new NodeA();
node.MessageVisualizer = new NullVisualizer();//don't visualize
node.DoSomethingThatMightVisualize();
```

Now based on the user's choice you can create NodeA or NodeB. But visualizer stays the same.

Comment: Can you elaborate with some codes maybe? I'm struggling to visualize what you are saying. I was thinking of composition, but couldn't get through the virtual hookers.

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen There are several ways to achieve the thing, Updated my answer to show some code using strategy pattern. Hope that helps. Should you still have questions? Feel free to comment. Thanks.

Comment: I guess this will work, I can't get my hands to my code right now. As soon as I handle it I'll let you know and accept your answer if works.

Answer (score 1):

[Strategy pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/776819/Strategy-Pattern-Csharp) looks like a good fit for your case. It defines a family of algorithms, encapsulate each one, and make them interchangeable. Strategy lets the algorithm vary independently from clients that use it. So this approach will help you with

> I have some different algorithms using the same base class, So I have inherited NodeA and NodeB from Node

Answer (score 0):

Another vote for the Strategy pattern.  It'd look something like this, I think (my C# is very rusty):

```
public interface IVisualizeMessageStrategy
{
    void VisualizeMessage(Message m);
}

public class Node
{
    public IVisualizeMessageStrategy VisualizeMessageStrategy ( Message m ) { get; set; }

    protected override void UserDefined_ReceiveMessageProcedure ( Message receivedMessage )
    {
        /// real implementation lies here
        ....
        /// VisualizeMessage is called in here
        this.VisualizeMessageStrategy.VisualizeMessage(receivedMessage);
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
Node nodeA = new Node();
nodeA.VisualizeMessageStrategy = new InstanceOfAlgorithmOneAsAClass();

Node nodeB = new Node();
nodeB.VisualizeMessageStrategy = new InstanceOfAlgorithmTwoAsAClass();
```

You don't need a NodeA class or a NodeB class.  You assemble them at runtime based on which algorithm you want to use.

Comment: Okay, and what about the `NodeA`, `NodeB` and the `VisualNode`